# Gallery scroll when click on button?

Tags: android

I have a view , my view contains gallery and two button.Here i want to scroll gallery when we click on buttons (just one position),for that i used following code,

this code for next position,

```
mBtnGalleryNext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             mGallery.scrollTo(180, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

this code for previous position,

```
mBtnGalleryPrevious.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             mGallery.scrollTo(0, 180);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

it is not working properly . please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `scrollTo()` method, use [`setSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29). 
If you call it like so:

```
setSelection(currentPosition+1, true);
```

It will scroll to the next position.

Comment: Thanks...This is working for next...please tell me for previous please

Comment: currentPosition-1 instead of +1 ;)